# replace version in maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

I have this piece of code in my pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <finalName>bonanza-{version}</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

but {version} is not replaced for the version of the project

```
 <groupId>com.bonanza</groupId>
    <artifactId>bonanza-lines</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be `${project.version}`